# Why does Closure Compiler break this AngularJS script?

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0, angularjs, google-closure-compiler

I'm testing AngularJs with Play Framework 2.0 (Scala). Play uses Closure to minimize Javascript files.

My file is as follows:

```
// Define a Module 'todoList' for Angular that will load the views. In this example the views are very simple, it's just to show
// the concept
angular.module('todoList', ['taskDoneFilter', 'todoServices']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/all', {templateUrl: 'assets/angular/all.html',   controller: TodoCtrl}).
            when('/task/:id', {templateUrl: 'assets/angular/task.html', controller: TaskDetailCtrl}).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/all'});
    }]);


// This filter allows us to convert strings. In this case, it adds an extra tick besides a task indicating if it's done or no
angular.module('taskDoneFilter', []).filter('checkmark', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input ? '\u2713' : '\u2718';
    };
});


// When running tests with Jasmine the jsRoutes object is not defined, which means we need to use a default route for the http call below
// This kind of defeats the purpose of retrieving the routes via Play instead of hardcoding them, as we need a fallback for the tests
// but I decided to leave the code just to see that we have the possibility, in case I find a way to improve this.
var tasksUrl = '/tasks/all';
if(!(typeof jsRoutes === "undefined")) {
  tasksUrl = jsRoutes.controllers.Application.tasks().url ;
}

// Definition of a Service, that stores all the REST requests independently from the controllers, facilitating change
angular.module('todoServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('All', function ($resource) {
        return $resource(tasksUrl, {}, {
            //The data model is loaded via a GET request to the app
            query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true}
        });
    })
    .factory('Task', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('tasks', {}, {
            add: {method: 'POST'}
        });
    });

/**
 * This is the controller behind the view, as declared by ng-controller
 * All references to methods and data model in the view map to this controller
 * @param $scope model data injected into the controller
 * @constructor
 */
var TodoCtrl = ['$scope', 'All', 'Task', function($scope, All, Task) {
    // We use the service to query for the data
    $scope.todos = All.query();

    //when submitting the form, this is called. Model in the form is referenced (todoText) and we add the task to
    //the data model
    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        var txt = $scope.todoText;
        $scope.todos.push({text: txt, done: false});
        Task.save({msg: txt});
        $scope.todoText = '';  //clear the input!
    };

    // calculates the remaining todos, automatically called when the model changes to update the view
    // notice the use of 'angular' component for functional approach
    $scope.remaining = function() {
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
            count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
        });
        return count;
    };

    //another acton triggered by click (in this case on an anchor), which archives completed tasks
    $scope.archive = function() {
        var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
        $scope.todos = [];
        angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
            if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
        });
    };
}];

// Task details controller, used in the routes to provide a second view for the application
var TaskDetailCtrl = ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
}];
```

But when minimizing, it becomes:

```
var module$todo={};angular.module("todoList",["taskDoneFilter","todoServices"]).config(["$routeProvider",function($routeProvider){$routeProvider.when("/all",{templateUrl:"assets/angular/all.html",controller:TodoCtrl$$module$todo}).when("/task/:id",{templateUrl:"assets/angular/task.html",controller:TaskDetailCtrl$$module$todo}).otherwise({redirectTo:"/all"})}]);angular.module("taskDoneFilter",[]).filter("checkmark",function(){return function(input){return input?"\u2713":"\u2718"}});
var tasksUrl$$module$todo="/tasks/all";if(!(typeof jsRoutes==="undefined"))tasksUrl$$module$todo=jsRoutes.controllers.Application.tasks().url;angular.module("todoServices",["ngResource"]).factory("All",function($resource){return $resource(tasksUrl$$module$todo,{},{query:{method:"GET",params:{},isArray:true}})}).factory("Task",function($resource){return $resource("tasks",{},{add:{method:"POST"}})});
var TodoCtrl$$module$todo=["$scope","All","Task",function($scope,All,Task){$scope.todos=All.query();$scope.addTodo=function(){var txt=$scope.todoText;$scope.todos.push({text:txt,done:false});Task.save({msg:txt});$scope.todoText=""};$scope.remaining=function(){var count=0;angular.forEach($scope.todos,function(todo){count+=todo.done?0:1});return count};$scope.archive=function(){var oldTodos=$scope.todos;$scope.todos=[];angular.forEach(oldTodos,function(todo){if(!todo.done)$scope.todos.push(todo)})}}];
var TaskDetailCtrl$$module$todo=["$scope","$routeParams",function($scope,$routeParams){$scope.id=$routeParams.id}];
```

And then it stops working. Notice the:

```
var module$todo={};
```

and

```
var TodoCtrl$$module$todo=
```

which break the app.

Anyone knows why may this be happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `All` & `Task` services are not 'minify safe'. You must use the [array notation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

```
angular.module('todoServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('All', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource(tasksUrl, {}, {
            //The data model is loaded via a GET request to the app
            query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true}
        });
    }])
    .factory('Task', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('tasks', {}, {
            add: {method: 'POST'}
        });
    }]);
```

Also, define your controller with `angular.module(...).controller()`:

```
angular.module(...).controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', 'All', 'Task', function($scope, All, Task) {
}]);
```

Comment: IMHO the ONLY dependency injection mechanism allowed should be array notation.

Comment: apologies for delay accepting answer, I had to verify and couldn't do it until today!

Answer (score 0):

... and if you have a larger app, you can find where you aren't using named references by turning on strictDi (option to bootstrap call or ng-strict-di attribute in tag with ng-app attribute).